# Can we create video calling using ionic3?

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

I am working on ionic3 , I want to create video calling application . Is it possible to create video calling application in ionic3 . please let me know... thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please edit the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. you may find the flow at below resource links  :

1. https://github.com/nakulkundaliya/ionic-3-video-calling-using-webrtc
2. https://blog.ivrpowers.com/post/coding/videortc-build-mobile-app/

Comment: Thank you for reply me. I had used link 1 and when I run code into web and use two browser for call then I got error User_Media_Error also When I create apk and install it into mobile and try to call another user I got same error and on mobile did not activate camera and audio. please help me....